# Push the right aligned element down when the first left element is too long

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

[image]

I'm trying to achieve this, where brown gets pushed down when pink is too long, and pink is dynamically sized based on its text content.

I was only able to achieve this using javascript and two templates, if pink length is over X use second template, but I'm wondering if there's a way to achieve this using CSS only?

I tried meddling with grid auto-fill/auto-fit with minmax, float, flex with wrap, but I couldn't get to the desired result with these.

```css
.parent {
  width: 170px;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
 }

div {
  outline: 2px solid rgba(255, 0,0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>scenario A</p>
  <div class="parent flex">
    <div>
      <div class="one">A short title</div>
      <div class="three">Some text here</div>
      <div class="three">some more text</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button>A button</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <p>scenario B</p>
  <div class="parent">
      <div class="one">Testing a very long title</div>
      <div class="flex">
        
      <div>
        <div class="three">Some text here</div>
        <div class="three">some more text</div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button>A button</button>
      </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

<p>can a component achieve both a and b with only css?
```

Comment: Not possible with CSS-Grid or flexbox.

Comment: is it possible with CSS at all?

Comment: Maybe using `float` but it will depend on your HTML structure.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, it requires having fixed height in the first row, and the right side button will basically overflow when needed.

Will wait a bit before accepting my own solution in case someone came with a better one.

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.text {
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 0;
}

.first-row {
  height: 22px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  gap: 8px;
}

.image {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #444;
}

.title {
  flex-grow: 1;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<h2>Long title</h2>
<div class="container">
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="text">
    <div class="first-row">
      <div class="title">Test title test title test title</div>
      <button>Visit store</button>
    </div>
    <div class="three">in the stores</div>
    <div class="three">sponsored</div>
  </div>
</div>

<h2>Short title</h2>
<div class="container">
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="text">
    <div class="first-row">
      <div class="title">Short title</div>
      <button>Visit place</button>
    </div>
    <div class="three">in the stores</div>
    <div class="three">sponsored</div>
  </div>
</div>

<h2>Very long title</h2>
<div class="container">
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="text">
    <div class="first-row">
      <div class="title">Test title test titleTest title test titleTest title test title</div>
      <button>Visit place</button>
    </div>
    <div class="three">in the stores</div>
    <div class="three">sponsored</div>
  </div>
</div>
```